# How to enable IntelliSense for C++ in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm coding in C++ using Visual Studio Code but IntelliSense doesn't seem to work, I've downloaded the extension and used the IntelliSense reset command but it still refuses to work. What should I do?

Comment: I assume you mean Visual Studio Code. Although when I tried to edit your title it said there already exists a question with the exact same title.

Comment: Yea visual studio code :)

Comment: Have you gone through their docs?
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Comment: Yes, I still dont know what to do, I have "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"

Comment: If you mean the engine, check if "Intelli Sense Engine" is set to "Default" (the alternatives beeing: "Tag Parser" or "Disabled").

Answer (score 2):

Once you have downloaded and installed the extension from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools), you will have to reload VS, then go to extensions (ctrl+Shift+X) and verify that the extension is enabled:

[image: Extension should look like in this picture]

Just after that, once you create a c++ file (.cpp) intellisense should be enabled as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: Okay so it seems like I somehow had 2 different versions of intellisense installed at the same time, I disabled one of them and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Another point worth checking is that `C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine` is set to `default` in the `settings.json` file[image]